# JQuery: Can't access modified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I want to add `.close` class to the element when the mouse leaves and then I want to remove this class for reason.

```
$("#nav > li").mouseleave(function (){
    alert($(this).children(".subs").length);    // value 1
    $(this).children(".subs").addClass("close");
    setTimeout(function () { 
        alert($(this).children(".subs").length) 
    }, 500);    // value 0
});
```

After adding the class I can't access the element. What can I make this work?

HTML before action:

```
<div class="subs" id="service-subs" aria-haspopup="false">
    stuff
</div>
```

HTML after action:

```
<div class="subs close" id="service-subs" aria-haspopup="false">
    stuff
</div>
```

Comment: After you add `close` class, Inspect your html and check if the `.subs` still exists for the element.

Comment: It still. In addition, I get the same problem if I add a style addribute.

Comment: I want to see your html after `mouseleave` execution finishes. It difficulty to tell like this what might be the problem.

Comment: I expanded my question with my HTML.

Comment: It is because the `this` variable getting empty after event fire. The `setTimeout` function called when `this` variable has not value

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `this` variable getting empty after event fire and the `setTimeout` function called when `this` variable has not value. You can store value of `this` in another variable.

```
$("#nav > li").mouseleave(function (){
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.children(".subs").length);
    $this.children(".subs").addClass("close");
    setTimeout(function () { 
        alert($this.children(".subs").length) 
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this type of situation I would just use an arrow function like that:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  //$(this) would work here as you intended
}, 500);
```

Arrow functions (`()=>{}`) don't have `this` set by default. So it would go up until it finds a `this`. 
IMHO; It's the prefered way to do callbacks since ES6.